# DataGridView does not display ArrayList of objects

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my program in Visual Studio 2010 I have stored the content of a table using `SqlDataReader` into an `ArrayList`.

When i tried to display the list in the datagrid, The grid does in show the output.The list is confirmed to be populated with the data from the table.

Syntax I used for populating the grid was:

```
 DataGridView1.DataSource=list;
```

Note: The code doesnt generate any errors.
The full code is:

```
 namespace Assignment2_itemwarehouse
 {
   public partial class ViewAll : Form
     {
      SqlDataReader rdr;
      ArrayList list =  new ArrayList(); 
      public ViewAll(SqlDataReader rdr1)
        {

        InitializeComponent();
        rdr = rdr1;
         }

    private void btnback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void ViewAll_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            list.Clear();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {

                Item itm = new Item();
                itm.itemid = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[0]);
                itm.itemlookupcode = Convert.ToString(rdr[1]);
                itm.description = Convert.ToString(rdr[2]);
                itm.quantity = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[3]);
                itm.price = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr[4]);
                itm.cost = Convert.ToDecimal(rdr[5]);
                itm.salestype = Convert.ToString(rdr[6]);
                itm.salesstartdate = Convert.ToString(rdr[7]);
                list.Add(itm);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something Wrong here to view");

        }
    }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Are `itemid`, `itemlookupcode` (and the rest) fields or properties? (grid.dataSource needs them to be properties). also consider using `List<Item>` instead of ArrayList

Comment: Those are properties which are been defined inside a class Item.

Comment: i cannot reproduce the issue. arrayList populated with test items (without SqlDataReader) worked in my test project `var list = new ArrayList(); list.Add(new Item { itemid = 1, itemlookupcode = 100 }); list.Add(new Item { itemid = 2, itemlookupcode = 200 }); dataGridView1.DataSource = list;`

Comment: Should  the properties inside the class have same datatype?

Comment: 'code' public class Item
             {
          public int itemid;
                public int itemlookupcode;
                public String description;
               public int quantity;
               public decimal price;
               public decimal cost;
               public String salestype;
               public String salesstartdate;
               public int aliascode;

                } This is my Item class

Comment: properties types can be different

Comment: But its not working for me sir. The list is been populated. I tried it by debuggging. setting the datasource for gridview is the only suspected line

Comment: `public class Item { public int itemid; }` - `itemid` is not a PROPERTY it is a FIELD here! try make  it `public class Item { public int itemid {get; set;} }` (same for the rest fields)

Comment: fine. i warned you about that in my 1st comment, actually. also if you had posted code for `Item` earlier i would have explained the issue earlier.